# Making sense of hexadecimal value

Tags: c#, .net, hex

I'm a self-made programmer, therefore I don't know much about bits and bytes and hexadecimal values.

One of the libraries I use receives data from a remote service as byte array. I have found a method to convert this byte array data:

```
public string ByteArrayToHexString(byte[] buf)
{
    if (buf == null) return "";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(buf.Length * 2 + 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < buf.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(buf[i].ToString("x2"));
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Using this method I get strings like these:

```
0031
```

or

```
0022
```

or

```
002d
```

Are those actual values sent by the service or should further conversion required? What should I do to get the actual values?

Comment: `What should I do to get the actual values?` - we don't know. What do these represent?

Comment: What is the expected outcome required?

Comment: Good time to make yourself learn.

Comment: Given your method is called ByteArrayToHexString it looks like its doinf its job to me

Comment: As @Oded states, we can't possibly know what the `byte`s in an arbitrary `byte` `Array` represent and whether they are correct.

Converting the bytes to a string of hex literals won't really help much either way.

What is the signature of the web method and what do you expect it to do? The `byte[]` could be a binary serialization of any other type, it could be somthing else.

Comment: @user424950 did my answer help you to understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I'm going to make no attempt to answer the question as to what your byte values mean, or whether they are "correct", because we have no way of knowing, given the information presented here. Instead I'm going to take you through your conversion, step by step, to answer your question "Are those actual values sent by the service?"**

A `byte[]` is an array of bytes - a "byte array".

An array is a fixed size set of values.

A `byte` object in C# is a value whose range falls between the decimal numbers 0 and 255.

So a "byte array" is literally just a bunch of numbers, in order, all of which are between 0 and 255.

Hexadecimal values are just one way to visualise a byte array.

(And for complete clarity, hexadecimal is base 16, decimal is base 10.)

The numbers in the columns below are equivalent.

```
decimal    0     5    10    15    16    20     26     255
decimal    0    05    10    15    16    20     26     255  (padded with zero)
hex        0     5     a     f    10    14     1A      FF
hex        0    05    0a    0f    10    14     1A      FF  (padded with zero)
```

So imagine an array of bytes with the following decimal values:

```
4, 12, 255, 1, 0
```

That's equivalent to an array of bytes with the following hexadecimal values:

```
4, c, ff, 1, 0
```

That can also be written as:

```
04, 0c, ff, 01, 00
```

or more commonly:

```
0x04, 0x0c, 0xff, 0x01, 0x00
```

or:

```
04 0c ff 01 00
```

or:

```
040cff0100
```

So if your service is returning a byte array and you're seeing values like `002d`, that means, you received two bytes, first byte is 0 (0 is the same in base 10 and base 16), second byte is 2d (hex) which can also be expressed as 45 in decimal (base 10).

Short answer, notwithstanding anything you've not told us, **yes, those hexadecimal values do represent the actual values received from the service.**

Comment: Yes, buf[0] is 0x00 (decimal 0), and buf[1] is 0x22 (decimal 34). How does this relate to my answer?

Comment: It was  just a question.  And not of much value so I am deleting.  Thanks.

Comment: I realize that my question can't be answered without knowing the underlying structure. I will accept this info as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a byte array to a Hex string you'd probably be better using the built in [`BitConvertor.ToString(byte[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a733s97.aspx) method.

However, the actual value returned by the web method has a type of `byte[]`. Converting it to a hex string is just another way of representing it.

It may be more convienient to display it as a comma delimited list of decimal byte values.

```
byte[] returnValue = ...
var commaDelimmitedListOfByteValues =
    string.Join(",", returnValue.Select(v => c.ToString()));
```

This would give you somthing like `"1,254,23,67,111,23,..."`.

We can't speculate on the "true" meaning of the `byte[]` without knowing what it was returned from and why.

---

For what is worth, in this context

```
    "0031"           //Your Hex String
    "00-31"          //BitConvertor Hex String
    { 0, 49 }        //Array Inline Initializer
    "0,49"           //Comma delimited list of decimal byte values
    49               //Possible conversion to an Int32
    '1'              //Possible conversion to a Char
```

all these could be valid representations of the return value.

---

Could it be that?

> "0031" = '**1**'
>
> "0022" = '**"**'
>
> "002d" = '**-**'

all is speculation.

Comment: Wrong usage of the term "deserialization"